# jaxb2-maven-plugin creating packages by namespace

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb2

I have this issue with 
org.codehaus.mojo 
jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have various XSD-s and there are same elements/types in different xsd-s that belong to same namespace.

Now I wonder can I create packages for different namespaces so that I would not have double classes in them?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mvn-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <quiet>true</quiet>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                    <arguments>-mark-generated</arguments>
                </configuration>

                <executions>

                    <execution>
                    <id>teenus-meta</id>
                    <goals><goal>xjc</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/teenus1</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <packageName>ee.teenus</packageName>
                        <schemaFiles>one.xsd</schemaFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>vaetis</id>
                        <goals><goal>xjc</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/teenus2</schemaDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <packageName>ee.teenus2</packageName>
                            <schemaFiles>two.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
```

At this moment package1 and package2 contain same elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I need packages for different namespaces from various xsd. The solution found, is to use binding files. Maybe you should use binding files ...

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>one</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaFiles>one.xsd</schemaFiles>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingFiles>onebinding.xjb</bindingFiles>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            <extension>true</extension>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>two</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaFiles>two.xsd</schemaFiles>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingFiles>twobinding.xjb</bindingFiles>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            <extension>true</extension>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

onebinding.xjb

```
<jaxb:bindings jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" version="2.1"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/one.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.one" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xmlns/example1.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.one.example1" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

twobinding.xjb

```
<jaxb:bindings jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" version="2.1"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/two.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.two" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xmlns/example1.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.two.example1" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>    

</jaxb:bindings>
```